# How hide part photo and animate

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make such an effect ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yu1aztyj/)), but with two photos.
It occurred to me to use skewed div who would hide part of the image and the second image is below.
And I know not how.
Please help me.

I thank you.

Code:

html:

```
    <div id="container">
        <img src="https://s31.postimg.org/l6m2amhm3/img.jpg">
        <div class="man">
            <div class="color"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#container {
            height: 400px;
            width: 700px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #container div, #container img {
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .man {
            margin-left: 50%;
            width: 50%;
        }

        .man:hover > div {
            margin-left: -10%;
            width: 25%;
        }

        .color {
            background-color: rgb(181, 230, 247);
            margin-left: 20%;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            transform: skewX(11deg);
            width: 0;
        }
```

Comment: To make sure I understand how this is supposed to function. When hovered over Male the blue background should completely cover the Female side. And when hover over the Female, the male side should be completely covered. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, but not complety. I made [gif](https://s5.postimg.org/44q543q2v/cat_dog.gif)

Comment: Based on your GIF, your code accomplishes you goal.

Comment: Mouse enters .man div, .color expands. Mouse leaves .man div, .color retracts back to default position (which is the same position .color would be even if woman was hovered - unless you want .color to stay in expanded state after hover.

Comment: But, i want use two photos. I can not use a solid color.
Or I do not get it. You may possibly indicate the code?

I thank you very much.